# Platformer Crouching problems

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to implement a crouching system to my 2D platformer. The problem is, I don't want the character to be able to do anything else except jumping when it's crouching. I have many functions but I think posting the movement function here would be enough. When I gain velocity and then press crouch, I skid across the platform, and stop.

First, my crouch function:

```
private enum State { idle, running, jumping, falling, crouching}

    void Update()
{
    //crouch
    if(Input.GetButton("Crouch"))
        {
        animator.SetInteger("state", 4);
        Crouch();
        }
    else 
    {
    boxCol.size = new Vector2(0.5454721f, 1.8065f);
    }
}

 void Crouch()
{
    boxCol.size = new Vector2 (0.6933689f,1.44953f);

}
```

And here is my movement function. I tried to fix it by adding the if condition on top of it, but when I run and crouch, it slides a lot before stopping. What can I do to fix that? The character already has a physics material with zero friction. I know I can make the velocity zero if the player is crouching but that would just kill the gameplay. I need to add a smooth stopper. I'm not sure how to make a decelerating script and use it in my case.

```
public void Move()
{
     if(animator.GetInteger("state") != 4)
     {
            float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float moveBy = x * speed;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveBy, rb.velocity.y);
                if (x > 0f)
                {
                transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
                isRight = 1;
                isLeft = 0;
       

                }
                else if (x < 0f)
                {
                transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1, 1);
                isLeft = 1;
                isRight = 0;
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Zero friction means it is like ice. If it is really zero, you could just increase it which should reduce the distance it slides.

Comment: @Zibelas I did that to fix the issue where the player would get stuck on walls. I'll try playing with the player's AND the surface's friction, maybe that would work.